# Can't serve jquery javascript file with custom Jetty handler

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to build a simple app with embedded Jetty server that serves static files from a "templates" directory. This directory is a subdirectory of root directory of a project.

In this directory I use a static file "hello.html", which contains a line `<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>` for include jquery library to my project.

But when I start my project, I get this message from console of a browser: "jquery-3.3.1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". It was happend because including jquery library served by Jetty and return text of html page (see that in browser console in network tab).

How I can include jquery library to my project?

**HelloServer.java**

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;

public class HelloServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler();
        context.setContextPath("/hello");
        context.setHandler(new HelloServerHandler());

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(context);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

**HelloServerHandler.java**

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloServerHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(
            String target
            , Request baseRequest
            , HttpServletRequest request
            , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        response.getWriter().println(HelloServerPageGenerator.instance().getPage("hello.html"));
    }
}
```

**HelloServerPageGenerator.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class HelloServerPageGenerator {
    private static HelloServerPageGenerator helloServerPageGenerator;
    private static final String HTML_DIR = "templates";

    public static HelloServerPageGenerator instance() {
        if (helloServerPageGenerator == null) {
            helloServerPageGenerator = new HelloServerPageGenerator();
        }
        return helloServerPageGenerator;
    }

    public String getPage(String filename) {
        String content = "";
        try {
            content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(HTML_DIR + File.separator + filename)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(instance().getPage("hello.html"));
    }
}
```

**hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello server</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello server</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error:**
[Window with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMtOX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your handler only serves `hello.html`

The browser requested 2 resources from you ...

1. `http://<machine>:<port>/hello/` -> You served `hello.html` (this worked as expected)
2. `http://<machine>:<port>/hello/jquery-3.3.1.js` -> You served `hello.html` again (this didn't work as expected)

Your handler isn't smart enough (yet) to serve `jquery-3.3.1.js`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed description of the processing.

But how to make my handler smarter? :)